# Is it possible to omit "eval" in favor of "call" or "send" somehow in my case (Rails app)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, eval

I'm newbie in Ruby, so need help, because can not find answer :(

I have Rails application, which has model Event like this:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
before_validation :clean_input

....

protected

  def clean_input
    fields = %w[title preview content]
    fields.each do |field|
      eval "self.#{field} = ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize(self.#{field})"
    end
  end

end
```

The method purpose is cleaning input from dangerous data before validation and before storing it in DB.

Before I wrote this method it looked like the one below (with lot of duplication, that is not DRY at all). This code is very clear, but when adding new field I'll have to add new line instead of adding new element to an array:

```
  def clean_input
    self.title   = ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize(self.title)
    self.preview = ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize(self.preview)
    self.content = ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize(self.content)
  end
```

So my questions are:

1) is it possible to omit `eval ...` in favor of `call` or `send` somehow (all my attemps were useless)?

2) is it possible to declare `before_validation :clean_input` like this `before_validation clean_input: fields: { :title, :preview, :content}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Sure:

```
def clean_input
  %w(title preview content).each do |field|
    self.send("#{field}=", ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize(self.send(field)))
  end
end
```

2) No, and your current implementation is ok

Comment: @Зелёный I dont feel like its necessary to bother about such security in a private callback

Comment: @apneadiving Thanx, perfect! :) I had no idea it is so simple :)

Comment: @sawa You are right. I think in my case omitting `self` is ok :) At least it works the same :)

Comment: @sawa agreed, seems to reconfort people though, but I dont use it myself

Comment: Moved method contents to helper to reuse it, and now my code became DRY :) Thanx!

Answer (score 3):

Since you are updating an active record model, there are a few [other ways of updating attributes](http://www.davidverhasselt.com/set-attributes-in-activerecord/), for example:

```
def clean_input
  %i(title preview content).each do |field|
    self[field] = ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize(self[field])
  end
end
```

Comment: Oh, the second correct answer :) I start loving ruby :)

Comment: actually this one can introduce a subtle bug: you're not using the setter anymore, but working on the object directly, could be fine in most cases but beware...

Comment: what apneadiving is referring to is if you implement your own (non-empty) setter method - my method will not call it. This is very unconventional in ActiveRecord classes.

Comment: so, if I'm not mistaken, `send`ing in this case is not more secure, right or?

Comment: @kovpack - `send` is more _generic_. In your case, security is less relevant, since you are not using external input as the attribute names. If you really want to look at the differences, the default attribute setter and getter in AR are implemented _using_ the API used in my suggestion, so the `send` solution has two more stack frames than this one (which is inconsequential...)

Comment: Its good practice to use setters and not work on your objects directly. Not a `secure` issue, just good practice

Comment: just realize the same remark applies to the getter here

Comment: @apneadiving That is why your answer is selected as the better one, however, not more comfortable :)

Comment: ok, its interesting you had two approach to understand the underlying details